# Issue while performing Maven release to nexus from jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, nexus

I am trying to perform maven release to nexus in jenkins. I am getting the error  could not read Password for 'https://uname@github.developer.io': No such device or address.

is there any way we can use jenkins credentials and mention it in scm connection configuration?

Below are the configurations.

Added the servers in Maven settings xml:

```
<servers>
   <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
   </server>
</servers>
```

in pom xml added the below:

```
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>ADPNexus.Releases</id>
            <name>Nexus on ADP</name>
            <url>https://company-com/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ADPNexus.Snapshots</id>
            <name>Nexus on ADP</name>
            <url>https://company-com/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://uname:test@github.developer.io/company/esb-core.git</connection>
    <url>scm:git:https://uname:test@github.developer.io/company/esb-core.git</url>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://uname:test@github.developer.io/company/esb-core.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

jenkins Job configuration :

Git configurations:

Mentioned the repository url and Branches to build as */master

Build Goal

```
release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

Error log:

```
[INFO] [DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean)
[INFO] [DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[INFO] [DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
[INFO] <configuration>
[INFO]   <directory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
[INFO]   <excludeDefaultDirectories default-value="false">${clean.excludeDefaultDirectories}</excludeDefaultDirectories>
[INFO]   <failOnError default-value="true">${maven.clean.failOnError}</failOnError>
[INFO]   <followSymLinks default-value="false">${clean.followSymLinks}</followSymLinks>
[INFO]   <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
[INFO]   <reportDirectory default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}"/>
[INFO]   <retryOnError default-value="true">${maven.clean.retryOnError}</retryOnError>
[INFO]   <skip default-value="false">${clean.skip}</skip>
[INFO]   <testOutputDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
[INFO]   <verbose>${clean.verbose}</verbose>
[INFO] </configuration>
[INFO] [DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ core-parentnexustest ---
[INFO] [DEBUG] Using mirror AdpNexus (https://company-ca-nexus.dev.adp/repository/maven-public/) for apache.snapshots (http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository).
[INFO] [DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=3, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=3, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=4, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=3, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=36, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=10}
[INFO] [DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5:
[INFO] [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] [DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] [DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5
[INFO] [DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5
[INFO] [DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[INFO] [DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5
[INFO] [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
[INFO] [DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0
[INFO] [DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[INFO] [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean' with basic configurator -->
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) directory = /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE/target
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) excludeDefaultDirectories = false
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) followSymLinks = false
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE/target/classes
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) reportDirectory = /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE/target/site
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) retryOnError = true
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) testOutputDirectory = /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE/target/test-classes
[INFO] [DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] [DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE/target
[INFO] [DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE/target/classes
[INFO] [DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE/target/test-classes
[INFO] [DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE/target/site
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 0.822 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-10T19:03:15+01:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 24M/1930M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE && git add -- pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE && git rev-parse --show-toplevel
[INFO] Working directory: /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE && git status --porcelain .
[INFO] Working directory: /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE
[DEBUG] M  pom.xml
[DEBUG] ?? pom.xml.releaseBackup
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? pom.xml.releaseBackup
[DEBUG] ?? release.properties
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? release.properties
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE && git commit --verbose -F /tmp/maven-scm-1947998640.commit pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE && git symbolic-ref HEAD
[INFO] Working directory: /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE && git push https:********@github.developer.io/company/esb-core.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
[INFO] Working directory: /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.735 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-10T19:03:16+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/1472M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project core-parentnexustest: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: could not read Password for 'https://uname@github.developer.io': No such device or address
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project core-parentnexustest: Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://uname@github.developer.io': No such device or address

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://uname@github.developer.io': No such device or address

    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.scm.ReleaseScmCommandException: Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://uname@github.developer.io': No such device or address

    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.checkin(AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.performCheckins(AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmCommitPreparationPhase.runLogic(ScmCommitPreparationPhase.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.execute(AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:286)
    ... 34 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/jenkins/workspace/TEST_NEXUS_RELEASE/pom.xml to com.company.esb.testnexus/core-parentnexustest/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/core-parentnexustest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Comment: Typical problem in Jenkins, cause the jenkins does not really checkout the branch master...You need to configure jenkins to checkout a branch to get that working....

Comment: Hi,i have updated the Git configurations to checkout the branch master.Iam getting issue while commiting in GIT updated the error log.